# Why does the csproj have a different version than the installed nuget?

Tags: msbuild, csproj

When I create a new .csproj through Visual Studio and install version 12.0.2 Newtonsoft nuget via the Visual Studio interface, I see this in the `packages.config` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.2" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

Which is what I expect. However, I also see that the .csproj has been modified so it looks like

```xml
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Where the `Version` is 12.0.0.0. Where does this come from?

Comment: The author decided that the assembly uses different version numbers for file version and package version. That's why you see 12.0.2 and 12.0.0. Since you still use packages.config, you observe that.

Comment: If file version is the one the author decided was 12.0.0.0, I see in windows when I right click the assembly installed by the nuget that it is 12.0.2.23222. What is the file version you are referring to?

Comment: NVM, I see it. I opened the nuget in nuget package explorer, selected the dll and saw the "Full Name" property is 12.0.0.0, while the "AssemblyFileVersion" is 12.0.2.23222.